# Setting a primary taxonomy term

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have a term reference field on one of my content types that allows for multiple terms to selected (list of checkboxes).  Is there a way to identify one of the terms as the "primary term"?

I know that I could add a second term reference field, but I'm thinking something along the lines of a radio button next to each term's checkbox, that could be checked, indicating the primary term.

We're going to using this to help categorize a set of digital files, and the terms relate to specific sections the digital file could relate to.  Each file can have several terms associated with it.  However some of the files have a physical copy in our library and the physical copy can only sit in one specific section on the shelf.  We'd like a way to indicate where the physical copy is located, so being able to mark one of the selected terms as the primary term would allow us to change how it displays.

So it could look something like this:
[image: example of term display]
With 'foo' being the primary term.

Comment: Could you please explain details what you are trying to achieve? What do you mean by "primary term"? You can set default term per content type.

Comment: Edited to clarify